# How can I remove header when setting UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration in iOS16

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I have a view with section and list components, it has a top padding for each section.

```
struct NewListView: View {

@State private var list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    List {
      ForEach(list, id: \.self) { item in
        let isHeaderHidden = item != "1"
        if isHeaderHidden {
          Section(header: Text("\(item)")) {
            Text("Content with Header")
          }.onAppear {
            print("item\(item)")
          }
        } else {
          Text("Content without header")
        }
      }
    }
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    .listStyle(.plain)
    .navigationTitle("NavTitle")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
  }
 }
}
```

[image]

In order to remove the padding, I set the UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(`.headerTopPadding = 0`) like below but the header view appears for the section I don't need(The first section). 
How can I remove the header but also remove the top padding at the same time? 
 Thanks in advance.

```
init() {
if #available(iOS 16, *) {
  var configuration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .plain)
  configuration.headerMode = .supplementary
  configuration.headerTopPadding = 0

  let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: configuration)
  UICollectionView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIViewController.self]).collectionViewLayout = layout
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm currently facing a similar issue.

Comment: @miwic Yes I did. I posed my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by making a custom header view.

```
struct HeaderSectionView: View {
var title: String
let backgroundColor: Color
var body: some View {

let isHidden = title.isEmpty
if !isHidden {
  Rectangle()
      .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
      .frame(height: 28)
      .overlay(
          Text(title)
            .padding(.leading, 10), // You need this to add back the padding for the Text
          alignment: .leading
      )
} else {
  EmptyView()
    .frame(height: 0)
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
}
```

}
}

And applied the custom header for the Section class.

```
Section(header: HeaderSectionView(title: section.title ?? "")) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the sample. However, when I run this, there is no view, but the section header seems to have a minimum height and it has a blurred background. The blurred background becomes apparent when colourful content scrolls below. Did you manage to find a way to remove the minimum height or to get rid of the blur, or was this something that you didn't find?

Comment: @miwic Try to add .environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 0) inside NavigationView meaning putting the code after .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline). This removes the minimum height that has the blur background.